# pass button value to controller mvc with button type as button not submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass next or back value of my button value  to my action argument. It works fine with button type submit button does not work with button type button.

```
public enum CommandType { next, back }

<a href="#"><button id="backButton" tabindex="-1" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" name="command" value="back" type="button"> Back</button></a>


 <a href="#"><button id="nextButton" name="command" value="next" type="button">                   </button></a>

 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(RegistrationModel model, CommandType command)
        {
}

$("#nextButton").click(function (evt) {
                $("form").submit();
            }
    });



 $("#backButton").click(function () {
        $("form").submit();
    });
```

Comment: `<button type="button">` is not a form control - forms only post the name/value pairs of its successful controls

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ? also I think its better not to use .submit() whenever your button is clicked because it will always load your page or maybe that's your goal after all. But I highly suggest using ajax or some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a hidden field and on button click set the value for the hidden field.

```
   <input id="buttontype" type="hidden" name="command" />


$("#nextButton").click(function (evt) {
     $("#buttontype").val('next');
                $("form").submit();
            }
    });



 $("#backButton").click(function () {
   $("#buttontype").val('back');
        $("form").submit();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

On Form post you will get all the control which are part of Form, but not the controls which are outside form.

So in current case, you can take one Hidden field within your form.

And just set control Id to the field.

so your click code will look like,

`<input type="hidden"  id="senderid" name="senderid" />` --> Within Form

```
$("#nextButton").click(function (evt) {
                $("#senderid").val($(this)[0].id);
                $("form").submit();
            }
    });



 $("#backButton").click(function () {
        $("#senderid").val($(this)[0].id);
        $("form").submit();
    });
```

Comment: Sorry may be similar answer to above, I was typing my answer.